# Proving the Set of Solutions to $f'(x) = 0$ is Unbounded from Below for a Bounded, Non-convergent, Differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Here is my attempt at a proof, and I feel that it is too simple to be correct. Thanks in advance!

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded, differentiable everywhere, and does not converge as $x \to -\infty$, we aim to prove the set of solutions to $f'(x) = 0$ is unbounded from below.

**Proof**:
Assume $B$ is a lower bound for the set of solutions to $f'(x) = 0$. Consider the interval $(-\infty, B)$. Since $f$ is bounded and does not converge as $x \to -\infty$, $f$ must exhibit at least one change in direction in $(-\infty, B)$, implying a local extremum exists within this interval.

Due to $f$'s differentiability, Fermat’s Theorem applies, stating if $f$ has a local extremum at $x'$, then $f'(x') = 0$. Finding such $x' < B$ contradicts the assumption of $B$ being a lower bound. Therefore, the set of solutions to $f'(x) = 0$ is unbounded from below.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it.

Comment: Depending on your intended audience, you might want to expand on why $f$ must have a change of direction in $(-\infty, B)$. In general, you should not just state something is so unless you are confident that your audience would *immediately* recognize it as true. (For homework, you should consider your audience to be no more knowledgeable than your classmates are after reading the section, but before starting the homework.)

Comment: I wasn't sure what more I could write. I was thinking something like - because the function is bounded and does not converge, the function is neither monotonically increasing nor decreasing, hence it has to change direction at least once.